# Search / Filtering multiple fields in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am new in mvc 5. I want to have a search using multiple fields. I have this code but I don't know how to pass the values from the view

View:

```
<input type="text" name="Id">
<input type="text" name="Price">
<input type="text" name="Name">
```

Product Class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ProductSearchModel:

```
public class ProductSearchModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int? PriceTo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ProductBusinessLogic:

```
public class ProductBusinessLogic
{
    private YourDbContext Context;
    public ProductBusinessLogic()
    {
        Context = new YourDbContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(ProductSearchModel searchModel)
    {
        var result = Context.Products.AsQueryable();
        if (searchModel != null)
        {
            if (searchModel.Id.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Id == searchModel.Id);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name));
            if (searchModel.PriceFrom.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Price >= searchModel.PriceFrom);
            if (searchModel.PriceTo.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Price <= searchModel.PriceTo);
        }
        return result;     
    }
}
```

Product Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(ProductSearchModel searchModel)
{
    var business = new ProductBusinessLogic();
    var model = business.GetProducts(searchModel);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: To match your view model, you need inputs with `name="PriceFrom" and `name="PriceTo " (not `name="Price"`). Are you doing a normal submit (with `FormMethod.Get`) or sending it via an ajax call? And you should be passing an instance of `ProductSearchModel` to the view and using the strongly typed `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)` etc methods to generate the view

Comment: I am using FormMethod.Get

Comment: You should edit your question to include more details of the view. You will also need to add an additional property in `ProductSearchModel` for the collection, and return `searchModel` in the method